# Paste data frame without changing into factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I have vectors let say a,b,c,d as below:

```
 a <- c(1,2,3,4)
 b <- c("L","L","F","L")
 c <- c(11,22,33,44)
 d <- c("Y", "N", "Y","Y")
```

And I try to use paste to get this output (1):

```
paste(a,b,c,d, sep = "$", collapse = "%")
[1] "1$L$11$Y%2$L$22$N%3$F$33$Y%4$L$44$Y"
```

Then I change it into this, let say df:

```
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

and get this output (2):

```
paste(df, sep = "$", collapse = "%")
[1] "c(1, 2, 3, 4)%c(2, 2, 1, 2)%c(11, 22, 33, 44)%c(2, 1, 2, 2)"
```

My question is:
(1) Can somebody explain to me why in df it change its elements into numeric?
(2) Is there any other way that I can use df to get output (1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly apply `paste` to a dataframe for your case here, to get the desired output you need to apply `paste` in two levels.

```
paste(apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "$")), collapse = "%")

#[1] "1$L$11$Y%2$L$22$N%3$F$33$Y%4$L$44$Y"
```

Where the `apply` command creates a row-wise vector

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "$"))
#[1] "1$L$11$Y" "2$L$22$N" "3$F$33$Y" "4$L$44$Y"
```

and the next `paste` command merge these all together with `collapse` argument as "%".

Answer (score 4):

`paste` runs `as.character` (or something similar internally) on its `...` arguments, effectively deparsing the list.  Have a look at

```
as.character(df)
# [1] "c(1, 2, 3, 4)"     "c(2, 2, 1, 2)"     "c(11, 22, 33, 44)" "c(2, 1, 2, 2)"    
deparse(df$a)
# [1] "c(1, 2, 3, 4)"
```

Your code is pasting these values together.  To get around this, you can use `do.call`.

```
do.call(paste, c(df, sep = "$", collapse = "%"))
# [1] "1$L$11$Y%2$L$22$N%3$F$33$Y%4$L$44$Y"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative to the approach you used:

```
df_call <- c(df, sep="$")
paste(do.call(paste, df_call), collapse="%")

[1] "1$L$11$Y%2$L$22$N%3$F$33$Y%4$L$44$Y"
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `dplyr` approach:

```
pull(summarise(unite(df, tmp, 1:ncol(df), sep="$"), paste(tmp, collapse="%")))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
  unite(tmp, 1:ncol(df),sep="$") %>%
  summarise(output = paste(tmp, collapse="%")) %>%
  pull()
```